# Moya: Getting -999 (Aborted) errors

Tags: swift, moya

I'm using RxMoya and see a lot of -999 errors in my console. But data seems to be there.

I have seen that provider needs a strong reference and to check that I added a deeinit in MoyaProvider. But it never gets called. What could cause the -999 (Aborted)

```
myApp[92741:5981476] Task <40FD9BEF-D7A5-48F8-8569-1FEB342B4025>.<6> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://mywebserice.com, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://mywebserice.com, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <40FD9BEF-D7A5-48F8-8569-1FEB342B4025>.<6>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <40FD9BEF-D7A5-48F8-8569-1FEB342B4025>.<6>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]
```